# How to have an iteration as soon as page loads display?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently running this text animation through raw HMTL for my website which I found on codepen, I'm pretty new to this coding thing and just wanna make my website look good, is there a way to not display when "onmouseover" but instead to display once at website load and that's all. Thanks ! Here is the json script:

```
<script>

const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.querySelector("h2").onmouseover = event => {  
  let iteration = 0;
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iteration) {
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
      
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");
    
    if(iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length){ 
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    iteration += 1 / 3;
  }, 30);
}

</script>
```

I tried to change the event but I couldn't find a "pageload" or something event, or a way to limit it to 1 time after each load.

I tried this:

```
<script>

const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.querySelector("h2").onLoad = event => {  
  let iteration = 0;
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iteration) {
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
      
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");
    
    if(iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length){ 
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    iteration += 1 / 3;
  }, 30);
}

</script>
```

And this:

```
document.querySelector("h2") = function(){<script>

const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.querySelector("h2").onmouseover = event => {  
  let iteration = 0;
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iteration) {
          return event.target.dataset.value[index];
        }
      
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");
    
    if(iteration >= event.target.dataset.value.length){ 
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    iteration += 1 / 3;
  }, 30);
}

</script>};
```

Didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, if it does what you want.

```
<script>

const animation = () => {
  const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  let interval = null;

  const h2El = document.querySelector("h2");  
  let iteration = 0;
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    h2El.innerText = h2El.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iteration) {
          return h2El.dataset.value[index];
        }
      
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");
    
    if(iteration >= h2El.dataset.value.length){ 
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    iteration += 1 / 3;
  }, 30);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  animation();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I needed ! You helped me understand my mistake ! I hope you have a nice day :)